# how can i add query in react router

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

this is now

`http://localhost:8001/components/button/`

I want to

`http://localhost:8001/components/button/?theme=dark`

I used

```
browserHistory.push({
  pathname: '',
  query: {theme: dark},
})

and

browserHistory.push({
  pathname: 'components/button',
  query: {theme: dark},
})

and 

browserHistory.push({
  pathname: 'button',
  query: {theme: dark},
})
```

**All failed.**

How can i do? Can you help me, thank you!

Comment: can't you just do `browserHistory.push("/components/button/?theme=dark")` or try `browserHistory.push({ pathname: 'components/button', search: '?theme: dark', })`

Comment: @dikuw  result is localhost:8001/components/button/components/button/?theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `string literal` and push onto history.

```
browserHistory.push(`components/button?theme=${dark}`)
```

Comment: I used. it is same like ` pathname: 'components/button',`  and result is http://localhost:8001/components/button/components/button/?theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `push` method as:

```
browserHistory.push({
  pathname: '/components/button',
  search: '?theme=dark'
})
```

or simple as:

```
browserHistory.push('/components/button?theme=dark')
```

Comment: It will be /components/button/components/button/?theme=dark

Comment: this is /components/button/ ,  not  /components/button .  So it does't work.